# Visual Studio Code Unable to Resolve Imports from Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

The project was originally created in Eclipse so all imports work fine. However when opened in VSCode, the imports fail to resolve. I have downloaded the [Java Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack).

[image: vscode_unresolved_imports]

Anything I may be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to configure VSCode to point to the settings.xml in User Settings:

```
"java.configuration.maven.userSettings": "C:/apache/apache-maven-3.5.0/conf/settings.xml"
```

Then modify settings.xml to point to default local .m2 repository:

```
<localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
```

It should have been set by default but this is what worked for me.